Instrumentation conflicts occur when multiple processes use jacoco
Two java processes read the same class file at the same time. When the second process is instrumented, an instrumentation conflict error occurs.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot process instrumented class ext/mt/lion/Environment. Please supply original non-instrumented classes.
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_ff34e40.core.internal.instr.InstrSupport.assertNotInstrumented(InstrSupport.java:238)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_ff34e40.core.internal.instr.ClassInstrumenter.visitField(ClassInstrumenter.java:56)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_ff34e40.asm.ClassVisitor.visitField(ClassVisitor.java:287)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_ff34e40.asm.ClassReader.readField(ClassReader.java:907)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_ff34e40.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:683)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_ff34e40.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:400)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_ff34e40.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:89)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_ff34e40.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:107)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         ... 24 more
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin - java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException: Error while instrumenting ext/mt/lion/Environment$Appenv.
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_ff34e40.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:95)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:246)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:563)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at ext.mt.lion.Environment.loadAppenv(Environment.java:153)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at ext.mt.lion.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:234)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at ext.mt.lion.LionUtil.batchGetLionValue(LionUtil.java:68)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at ext.mt.lion.LionQueue.execute(LionQueue.java:80)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at wt.queue.ScheduleQueueEntry.execute(ScheduleQueueEntry.java:264)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at wt.queue.ScheduleQueue.execEntry(ScheduleQueue.java:344)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at wt.queue.ScheduleQueue.execEntries(ScheduleQueue.java:465)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at wt.queue.ScheduleQueueThread.processReadyEntries(ScheduleQueueThread.java:284)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at wt.queue.ScheduleQueueThread.run(ScheduleQueueThread.java:92)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin - Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while instrumenting ext/mt/lion/Environment$Appenv.
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_ff34e40.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrumentError(Instrumenter.java:160)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_ff34e40.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:109)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_ff34e40.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:92)
INFO  : wt.system.err wcadmin -         ... 25 more

Theoretically, the two processes read class files separately. Logically, this problem should not occur.
I expect the second process instrumentation to succeed
